# Android Camera preview stretched even after setting available size

Tags: android, camera, preview, stretch

I am working on my custom camera on android device.The preview is full screen activity.
To solve the stretch problem I use the codes like this:

```
private Camera.Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Camera.Size> sizes, int w, int h) {
    double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.1;
    double targetRatio=(double)h / w;
    if (sizes == null) return null;
    Camera.Size optimalSize = null;
    double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    int targetHeight = h;
    for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
        double ratio = (double) size.height / size.width;
        if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE) continue;
        if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
            optimalSize = size;
            minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
        }
    }
    if (optimalSize == null) {
        minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
            if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
            }
        }
    }
    return optimalSize;
}

//optimalSize 
myParam.setPreviewSize(optimalSize.width,optimalSize.height);
mCamera.setParameters(myParam);
mCamera.startPreview();
```

yes ,it works in almost of devices.But in some device it does't work! what ever size i setted which the device was supported,it does't work! so what's wrong?

Comment: the resolution of my phone is 1080*1920.I get the list of camera supported size form the code "myParam.getSupportedPictureSizes()",but it has no some size.
I tried setPreviewSize of the value 720*1280 and 1088*1920 that the device camera supported.but it did't work.